# How to turn off the block of content heading?

Tags: magento-1.8, blocks, local.xml

I want to turn off the **content heading block**, any idea how I can do it from **local.xml**?

When I echo this in my template phtml file,

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
```

I will always get this **content beading block** which I don't need,

```
frontend\base\default\template\cms/content_heading.phtml
```

I tried with these two guesses but they don't work of course,

```
<remove name="content_heading"/>
<remove name="content.heading"/>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<cms_page>
    <reference name="content">
        <remove name="page_content_heading"/>
    </reference>
</cms_page>
```